Nav On Click - Previous + Next
Apologize in advance as I'm inexperienced to web coding.
I have a slideshow on my website where I'm hoping to have the following:

Clicking on left side of window will go to previous slide
Clicking on right side of window will go to next slide

Here is my website: http://danielseunglee.com/projects
I currently have the code for clicking on anywhere in the window will go to next slide only here:
.nav-on-click .flickity-button svg {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

.nav-on-click .flickity-button.flickity-prev-next-button.next {
  transform: none !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}

I have the following so far and feel like I'm close but not sure exactly what to do:
.nav-on-click .flickity-button svg {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

.nav-on-click .flickity-button.flickity-prev-next-button.previous {
  transform: none !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  width: 50% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}

.nav-on-click .flickity-button.flickity-prev-next-button.next {
  transform: none !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  width: 50% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}


Any help would be highly appreciated!
